# Converting a list of numbers in Excel to Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I need help on a project of mine. I have an excel worksheet that has two columns of values that I need to convert into lists in python. Is there a way to read and copy excel columns into python?

Comment: Yes. There is. http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: However, asking for an external resource or library is specifically off-topic here. I've voted to close your question for that reason. And a quick google could have led you straight to that page.

Comment: If you run into difficulties using Python and Excel and have a specific piece of code, feel free to ask questions about *that*. Do check out if the question hasn't been asked before, however. There is a [`xlrd` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlrd) here on the site for you.

Answer (score 4):

Save the Excel sheet in .csv format. Then use the Python csv module to read it.